# Automatically creating java objects from json?

Tags: java, android, json, image, parsing

I have been experimenting with Android apps and using JSON from API's to come up with cool JSON objects and I know that there are libraries for parsing the JSON objects to Java objects, but, when there is a huge JSON file which is constantly changing parameters each time a user opens the app, how do I do it that java creates and converts the JSON objects to Java objects for me to use in my app?

However, I am using the Tumblr API in which gives a JSON response. I want to convert that response to a bunch of images, however, there can be hundreds of images on a blog and I can't make hundreds of Java objects each corresponding to each respective JSON object. That is where my problem is, performing the JSON parsing on a bigger scale.

If you want to see actual code/JSON script please comment although I didn't see the necessity in it yet, more of a general question.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. If you know how to create the java object from JSON, what's the problem?

Comment: Let me specify in the question a bit more

Comment: So you're looking for more of a streaming JSON converter where you parse the JSON to get an object, handle the object, and then go on to parse the next object? GSON does support parsing from a stream https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

Comment: Is that what unify was referring to?

Comment: No, @unify is referring to an intermediate JSON parsing structure where the JSON is parsed but the end objects are not created until you specifically request it. It can be more memory efficient depending on what you're doing but streaming will be the most efficient, assuming you don't need to keep the objects around.

Comment: Well I need them to display images on the device so I'd need to use a chache manager (I don't know if this makes a difference).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, there's always a trade off between flexibility and structure. If your JSON does change frequently, but in a predictable way, the most flexible approach is the good old JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(someJsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("someJsonArray");
String value = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).getString("someJsonValue");
```

Reference: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

If you are talking about generating new POJOS every time there's a change in the schema (API version for example), you could try a tool like:
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ or
http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/
They are great time savers.

Comment: But what if it's all in one big JSON file. How would I segregate each object instead of creating just big object with all the values?

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy!  use `jackson` and `lombok`.
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial#2-json-to-java-object

```
import lombok.Data;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Data
public class Car {

    private String color;
    private String type;

    // standard getters setters will be available from Lombok
}


String json = "{ \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"BMW\" }";
Car car = objectMapper.readValue(json, Car.class);  

// Now you can use car object. Ex: car.getColor()
car.getColor() // = Black
```